# Put everything in ordered groups, but have chars in parentheses grouped together

Tags: regex, dart

Say I have this string:

> 111 222 (333 444) 555 666 (777) 888

What I want is:
Group 1: 111 222
Group 2: 333 444
Group 3: 555 666
Group 4: 777
Group 5: 888

I have this regex `\(([^\)]+)\)` but it only captures what's between parens.

Comment: Could perhaps just do `string.split(RegExp(r"[()]"))`, assuming that the parentheses are matched anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```dart
String text = "111 222 (333 444) 555 666 (777) 888";
RegExp rx = new RegExp(r'\(([^()]+)\)|[^()]+');
var values = rx.allMatches(text).map((z) => z.group(1) != null ? z.group(1)?.trim() : z.group(0)?.trim()).toList();
print(values);
// => [111 222, 333 444, 555 666, 777, 888]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDPf02/1). The output is either trimmed Group 1 values, or the whole match values (also trimmed) otherwise. The `\(([^()]+)\)|[^()]+` pattern matches a `(`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than parentheses and then matches a `)`, or matches one or more chars other than parentheses.

To avoid empty items, you may require at least one non-whitespace:

```
\(\s*([^\s()][^()]*)\)|[^\s()][^()]*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDPf02/3). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\s()][^()]*)` - Group 1: a char other than whitespace, `(` and `)`, and then zero or more chars other than round parentheses
- `\)`  - a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `[^\s()][^()]*` - a char other than whitespace, `(` and `)`, and then zero or more chars other than round parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the string by identical characters, I would consider using a stack to keep a running storage of the congruent, consecutive characters. Once you reach a character that does not match, you can clear the entire stack until it is empty.

You can add more code (if statement logic) to keep populating a stack once an opening parentheses is read until a closing parentheses is read.